# CS1002 Error in ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone help me with this kind of error?

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

This seems to cause the error:

```
Line 69:                    string code = grdViews.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
Line 70:                     
Line 71:                        IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()where i.Field<String>("Code").Equals(code)select i;
Line 72:                        DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
Line 73:                         DetailsView1.DataSource = detailTable;
```

This is the sourcecode:

```
protected void grdViews_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
     {
         int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         string code = grdViews.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();

         IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()where i.Field<String>("Code").Equals(code)select i;
         DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
             DetailsView1.DataSource = detailTable;
         DetailsView1.DataBind();
         System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
         sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
         sb.Append("$('#currentdetail').modal('show');");
         sb.Append(@"</script>");
         ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
                               "ModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
    from i in dt.AsEnumerable()where i.Field<String>("Code").Equals(code)select i;
```

is not valid. You need spaces in between the statements, like so:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
    from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where i.Field<String>("Code").Equals(code)
    select i;
```

Comment: another question, i already did that but there is another error here it is:
Line 70:                   
Line 71:                      IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
Line 72:                             from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
Line 73:                             where i.Field<String>("Code").Equals(code)
Line 74:                             select i;